# How do I write this SQL Query? Top 3 Most matching results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for a SQL query that gives me the top 3 most matching results.

Find ID contains attribute A,B,C

```
id   | attribs  | results (# of matches)
----+-----+-----+----
1    | A,B,C    | 3
2    | A        | 1
3    | A,B      | 2
4    | A,D      | 2 
5    | E        | 0
```

In this example, I would like to return id 1,3,4

Can this be done using SQL Query only?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thank you

Comment: What is your table structure? It is unclear whether each attrib is in its own row.

Comment: Could you just use the select top clause. i.e. SELECT TOP 3 id FROM theTable WHERE whatever

Comment: Each attrib has it's own row. So one row is like 1-A , 1-B, 1-C, 2-A, 3-A etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each attrib is in its own row:

```
select top 3 id
from MyTable 
where attrib in ('A', 'B', 'C')
group by id
order by count(distinct attrib) desc
```

Comment: I had to reverse group by and Where clause but it works! 
Thank you so much for your help!!!